# Argument Exception when creating JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

If I have this method:

```
public void doSomething (Dictionary<String, Object> data)
{
    JObject jsonObject = new JObject(data);
    ...
}
```

I get a `System.ArgumentException` on the line where I create the JObject. I'm using Newton-King's Json.net wrapper.

The error I get is:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is this NewtonSoft's JObject that you are using?

Comment: Posting your whole error is helpful as well.. is it `Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String].`?

Comment: @paqogomez The error message is `A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code`

Comment: Have you tried using JObject.Parse and passing in your json string?  I'm not sure if that would be the string, or object portion of your method, but parse returns a jobject.

Comment: Is there anything in the InnerException?

Comment: @paqogomez I'm using VS 2012 express, how do I see the InnerException?

Comment: InnerException should be one of the items in your exception detail. There is a nice [example image and explanation here](http://csharp.2000things.com/2013/08/06/)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The `JObject(object)` constructor is expecting the object to be either a `JProperty`, an `IEnumerable` containing `JProperties`, or another `JObject`.  Unfortunately, the documentation does not make this clear.

To create a `JObject` from a dictionary or plain object, use [`JObject.FromObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject.htm) instead:

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.FromObject(data);
```

To create a `JObject` from a JSON string, use [`JObject.Parse`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm), e.g.:

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""foo"": ""bar"", ""baz"": ""quux"" }");
```

Comment: how about creating a JObject from a string? How do you do that?

Comment: JObject.Parse(myJsonString)